# any reason to call fsync before a call to fstat

Tags: c, filesystems, fsync, fstat

I have a piece of legacy code that issues a call to `fsync` before a call to `fstat` to determine the filesize of the target file.  (specifically the code is only accessing st_size out of the stat struct.)

Having looked at the docs, I don't believe this is a necessary call, but I wanted the expert's opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a correctly implemented filesystem, issuing a call to `fsync` or `fdatasync` should not affect the result of any subsequent `stat`/`fstat`/`lstat` call. Its only effect should be that any unflushed writes and, in the case of `fsync`, any modified metadata are committed to permanent storage. `stat` and its variants will work just fine with cached writes, regardless of whether the actual data has made to permanent storage or not.

That said, whether `fstat` is needed in the piece of code that you are studying is a matter of semantics and depends on how the result of `fstat` is used. For example:

- If it is used due to the misconception that `fsync` needs to be called to be able to get current metadata with `stat`, then you can probably remove it.
- If it is used to e.g. write some sort of checkpointing data then it is not exactly irrelevant, although the call order might need to be reversed - for a growing file the checkpointing data would need to indicate portions of the file that have certainly made it to permanent storage, so it would make sense to call `fstat`, *then* call `fsync`* and then write the checkpoint information.
- If it is used as some sort of UI progress monitor for an I/O bound operation, it may make sense to display the amount of data that has been actually committed to disk. In that case, though, the precision of the monitor is non-critical, so the call order may not matter that much.

So, how *is* the result of `fstat` used in your case?

*Disclaimer:* there may be filesystem implementations out there, e.g. networked/distributed ones where calling `fsync` may update the local client metadata cache for a file. In that case that `fsync` call may indeed improve the reliability of the code. If that is the case, however, then you probably have worse problems than just a little *performance* issue...

Comment: thanks for the note. Its a great answer. My problem is we are providing the result of fstat as a service and letting the caller to our utility function decide how to use it.  I think we can get away without calling it though, I just need to review our documentation and how it is used.